# Moving a label into 64bit register - inline assembly (GCC / CLANG)

Tags: gcc, assembly, inline-assembly

)
I'm trying to move a label's address into a 64bit register and it won't let me.

I'm getting a :

```
fatal error: error in backend: 32-bit absolute addressing is not supported in 64-bit mode
```

Here's an example of what i'm trying to do:

```
asm ("mov $label, %rax"); // Tried movq, movl (No difference)
...
asm volatile("label:");
...
```

Why won't it let me? does it allow moving a label only into a 32 bit register?
I have to insert that label's address into a 64bit register, how do I achieve that then?

thanks

Comment: You probably can avoid assembler code using computed gotos, i.e. [labels as values](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Labels-as-Values.html) GCC extension.

Comment: Did you try moving it to `eax`? I think it means just what it says. You're in Mac OS X right?  I think all 64-bit code on Mac is required to be `rip` relative.  Absolute addresses are not supported, so you can't load one in a register.

Comment: As written, I was able to compile this code without error.  You will need to provide more details/context.  Also, you do know that "asm statements may not perform jumps into other asm statements" (https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Extended-Asm.html), right?  Perhaps you should describe what you are actually trying to do so a more useful answer can be provided.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try either of these two asm statements:

```
asm ("movabs $label, %rax");
asm ("lea label(%rip), %rax");
```

The first one uses a 64-bit immediate operand (and thus a 64-bit absolute relocation), while the second one uses RIP relative addressing. The second choice is probably the best as it's shorter, though it requires that `label` be within 2^31 bytes.

However, as David Wohlferd noted, your code is unlikely to work.